# get most visited pages in sitecore by using Analytics's API

Tags: c#, sitecore

I want to get most visited pages in sitecore by using Analytics's API .

I am using below code to get this:

```
Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataSets.VisitorDataSet.PagesDataTable pagesDataTable = new VisitorDataSet.PagesDataTable();

var Count = pagesDataTable.Count(p => p.ItemId.ToString() == "{B0358D8A-A3B7-4D99-B123-78E7B1CA9F83}");
```

But its giving me `0` count all time . My Analytics database is enabled. I am not sure if am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you 0 because you instantiate it as `new VisitorDataSet.PagesdataTable()`

In my solution I'm doing something like this:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["analytics"].ConnectionString;
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

var query = "SELECT itemid, count(Url) as NumberOfVisits FROM [" + builder.InitialCatalog + "].[dbo].[Pages] group by itemid order by NumberOfVisits desc";
```

Although obviously this is not using any best practices (hardcoded SQL) and uses SQL to get to the data, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we used on the latest version of Sitecore (7.2 currently)

```
    //Sitecore query syntax
    //You must use the symbols {0} and {1} around all table and field names. 
    //You must use the symbols {2} and {3} around parameters. 
    //You must use the symbol {4} to insert a quote and symbol {5} to insert a wildcard. 
    //You must use the symbol {6} to insert an empty string literal. 
    private const string _trendingQueryBase = @"SELECT TOP {0} {{0}}ItemId{{1}}, COUNT(*) as {{0}}Views{{1}}
                                                FROM {{0}}Pages{{1}}
                                                WHERE {{0}}DateTime{{1}} >= GETDATE() - {1}
                                                AND {{0}}Url{{1}} LIKE {{4}}/stories/{{5}}{{4}}
                                                GROUP BY {{0}}ItemId{{1}}
                                                ORDER BY {{0}}Views{{1}} DESC";

    public IEnumerable<Guid> Get(int? topPagesToGet = 5, int? fromPastDays = 7)
    {
        var trendingQuery = string.Format(_trendingQueryBase, topPagesToGet, fromPastDays);
        var result = DataAdapterManager.Sql.ReadMany(trendingQuery, reader => DataAdapterManager.Sql.GetGuid(0, reader));
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get most visited pages with below function -

```
public List<Guid> GetMostPopularArticles()
            {
                string where = "Where it.TemplateID = {2}TemplateCondition{3} OR it.templateID ={2}SecoundTemplateId{3} ";
                string CommandText = @"SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT pa.ItemId, it.TemplateID, pa.PageViewCount 
                                                FROM (SELECT {0}ItemId{1},COUNT(*) AS {0}PageViewCount{1} 
                                                    FROM [lp_analytics].[dbo].[Pages] 
                                                        GROUP BY {0}ItemId{1}) AS pa 
                                                            INNER JOIN  [lp_master].[dbo].[Items] AS it ON  pa.ItemId =  it.ID 
                                                " + where + " ORDER BY pa.PageViewCount DESC";

                string firstTemplateId = ArticlePageItem.TemplateId.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
                string secoundTemplateId = RecipePageItem.TemplateId.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
                List<Guid> visitsId = DataAdapterManager.Sql.ReadMany<Guid>(CommandText, reader => DataAdapterManager.Sql.GetGuid(0, reader), new object[] { "TemplateCondition", firstTemplateId, "SecoundTemplateId", secoundTemplateId });
                return visitsId;
            }
```